# Unable to execute the else part of the if in the last line

Tags: python

When string is matched to the index without the else block in the if statment code works as expected.
But when else part is added it always displays "No string"

```
import sys


def string_search_index():
    '''
    This function search a string in a file through index and gives the result.    

    '''
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Enter Two Arguments Only"
        sys.exit(1)

    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]
    #size = len(sys.argv)
    file_name = open("passwd", "r")
    #print "No of Argu ", size

    if sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    else:
        print "Enter Integer in 1st Argument"
        sys.exit(1)
    fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1

    for store_file in file_name:
        temp = store_file.split(":")
        search = temp[fieldindex]
        #print search 

        if stringsrch in search:
            print store_file
        else:
            print "No String"
            sys.exit(1)


string_search_index()
```

Comment: I think that's because it will exit after the first loop around the for statement.

Comment: please provide solution ?? what should in change ?

Comment: Your variable names are very confusing; `file_name` is actually the file, not its name; `store_file` is a line in the file. As Zarkonnen commented, you also exit if the field in the  _first_ line doesn't contain your search string which is probably not what you want

Comment: i want simple. If string is matched display record else show No string.

Comment: Then I suggest you start by removing the last `else` and figure it out from there.

Comment: if else part is removed its working fine...But i want the message to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string not found` test should be outside the `for` loop:

```
file = open("my_file", "r")
string_found = False
# Loop over the lines of the file
for line in file:
    temp = line.split(":")
    if test_string in temp[index]:
        print('Found it : {}'.format(line))
        string_found = True
# String not found case
if not string_found:
    print("String not found")
```

Comment: It will always check the last line of the file than :(

Comment: No, it will go through each line in the file and set the boolean `string_found` if it finds the `test_string`.

Comment: if each line is to be processed than it should be inside for loop

Comment: now what should i do if the first argument exceed the length of total number of argument. I want that to be handled. where shuld i write that in code ?

Comment: In that case, `temp[index]` raises an IndexError. Use a try/except statement to catch that exception (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)).